# Как подкинуть свои куки?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requests, cookie, nestjs

В браузере тригерю метод, чтобы сделать запрос на сервере на сайт кинопоиска и спарсить страницу в личных целях (статистику получить). строку завпроса и отправляю header, но он делает проверку на бота.
Нужно как-то добавить куки чтобы у яндекса не было вопросов, как это сделать?

```
const config = {
"credentials": "include",
"headers": {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Host":"www.kinopoisk.ru",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Referer": "https://www.kinopoisk.ru/showcaptcha?retpath=https%3A//www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/m_act%5Bbirthday%5D%5Byear%5D/1960/m_act%5Bwhat%5D/actor/m_act%5Border%5D/rating/m_act%5Bcount%5D%5Bactor%5D/5101/m_act%5Ball%5D/ok/page/3%3F_c7cc9b9173dc0bc8276fa80c390ff114&t=3/1621429395/3f153115fe9a18af27e39e4ee632e80c&s=af5f71fc59f40b5205cf46cb977550f2",
    "Cookie": "{80d610b6-da02-41ea-83a4-b0fd8b55799b}=value; tc=182; my_perpages=%7B%2210%22%3A200%7D; stars_sort_v5=01.170.10.70.181; mobile=no; i=VaBZ4XnhowGeARd1mqDQdsbx8N30mmptY86vk89Bq9d/MHTArf8t/vHzaDmL5SxSl+5gbsnzrBndZp1P5CJe+Vak+6w=; mda_exp_enabled=1; _ym_uid=1621416082187032313; _ym_d=1621429519; _ym_isad=2; yandexuid=1341078631621420902; mda2_beacon=1621425508468; cycada=pwLTWMAik1Dv7nZyHJfoR7RtTfYYeaiSGHeCzXoiSR8=; user_country=by; ya_sess_id=noauth:1621425508; sso_status=sso.passport.yandex.ru:synchronized; P…d=157; _csrf_csrf_token=GbVDiC7lEuvFt0BmEFpRgUdX-QCTxGjndWHnuJrJMvU; desktop_session_key=9708bc6cbb8b9d49a4516b0db835d44cd22c41463182515964a02874f5f4b6af88fcd3d9f93a38e01a585ffada4ea6ea32e1a6f9d8b95728fb90b546ab3f7cb40f150561c18a74236706b6b5eb65f1257b45234026fed927a6bb1f1794d5877a; desktop_session_key.sig=Rq4POyxMQQ3LnqFNQ_pA3WxQlTo; gdpr=0; spravka=dD0xNjIxNDI5NDEyO2k9ODIuMjA5LjIxMC44O3U9MTYyMTQyOTQxMjYxNDA3ODI4NztoPTRhMzdlNzI0NWI5MjNiZDNkOWJjN2QyNTZiOTQ2ZmFl; _ym_visorc=b; yandex_plus_metrika_cookie=true",
},
"method": "GET" as any
"mode": "cors",
"Secure": "true",
};
 this.httpService.get(request, config).subscribe(source => {
    const page: HTMLElement = source.data; 
    return console.log(page)
});
```

Возможно вообще или не нужно даже время пытаться тратить?

Comment: Из браузера никак. Браузер не даст вам подменить укуки.

Comment: из кода на беке